# chrome making copy of navigation bar with fixed at top in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a single page design with a navigation bar fixed at top using bootstrap but whenever I scroll the page and get back to top I see that there is a copy of navigation bar in the middle of the page.I tried reversing the contents position(section1->section3->section2) instead of
 (section1->section2->section3). But the problem still exist .

This problem is only in chrome I have tested on firefox and internet explorer and everything is fine but in edge browser the navbar becomes invisible. and after some time it comes back. dont know how.

I dont know which code is causing the problem (css ,js,jquery) so I am not pasting anything here I will paste the code as per all you direction.[image]

Comment: Did you try disable plugins, themes, etc. from browser?

Comment: yes i disabled the chrome theme plugin but it didn't helped me. @marcelo2605

Comment: I dont know why i marked as -1 for my question. I have searched and didn't find anything thats why asked the question.

Comment: @pawan I tried to vote it up.  I see more unexplained -1's here than on all of the other stackexchange boards combined.  Same happened to me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35377148/why-do-all-of-my-linux-based-email-clients-fail-to-authenticate-using-imap-gmail/35381295#35381295

Comment: @pawankumar You are downvoted because we don't see any code. It is like you are calling the doctor to help you diagnose, but not going to see him in person.

Comment: Can you please paste your code into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)  or something?

Comment: this is the jsfiddle for my navagation bar code https://jsfiddle.net/mgeLebym/   

this is the jsfiddle for about section where i get stuck https://jsfiddle.net/2faLcx7v/

Comment: this is the jsfiddle combining both navigation bar and about section https://jsfiddle.net/jzmvdxnv/   i will be very thankful if any solve my problem

Comment: But the problem is that it is not showing the problem in jsfiddle as i have stated in my question that the problem only occurs in chrome . I have tested it on other laptops too. the problem was there but not in jsfiddle if u need i can email u the full code .

Comment: latest jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jzmvdxnv/

Comment: From a first inspect your code seems to be correct. I'm seeing the code with Chrome and it looks ok here. Did you tested also on a fresh Chrome installation? (without any plugin or theme)

Comment: yes i have tried on my friends laptop and they all have this prolem   please use this fiddle jsfiddle.net/jzmvdxnv for full code and use it in ur chrome.